# Update ADT to latest version v23 or above current is 22.6.3 Dependency Error

Tags: android, eclipse

Before marking my Question as duplicate or anything please read it i have tried almost all the solutions avialable at stack but none worked for me.

I was using adt bundle, updated the SDK then ever since this error keep pop-ing up, [image]

When i try to update the ADT from https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse, it gives error 
[image]

Finally i tried to un-install all of the plugin that said v22... i tried it because i read it some where in stack answers but after doing that my eclipse would not start.

I have tried to un-install plugins individually as well but this wont work as well.

I also tried to install the ADT plugin through archive files, but it gives dependency error. Could anyone please tell me what's wrong and how to solve it and update my ADT to latest version.

Comment: You can download the latest ADT from the official site and skip all this mess.

Comment: they have replaced ADT by Android Studio now

Comment: I have faced this issue and I give up. So, I start to learn Android Studio tools and I can still build non-Android Java projects with it with a simple build.gradle